# http header to tell the site that not to send resources as data-uri?

Tags: http, browser, data-uri

is there an HTTP header to tell the site I'm visiting that my browser doesn't support data-uri like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAAAjCAIAAAD5ZGRzAAAIaElEQVRoge2aaVTU1xnGfzPDIiD7iOwqCGpIAkGqHiRqXJoakFhrtW1cmnpsUhvbJjU9Se2xOdbmWDk5pssxjVtNYm3SamMUTFOr4Rg8RlEqCoiyb8M2DMMMjMM20w/+w53/OClja8Ax83x673P
```

If not is there a site that presents an API so i send the base64 hash to it and it returns the image in image/png content-type ???

Answer (score 0):

your browser? are you building a browser?
to convert a base64 into image in js is very simple:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...';
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: I'm not building a browser but pretend so, i want to tell the site that my browser doesn't support data-uri